# JavaMelody change version from "javamelody-spring-boot-starter" to "javamelody-core"

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-melody

I need to change the Java Melody version, from "1.69.0" to "1.74.0", for a Java Spring Boot project.

Right now I have:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
    <artifactId>javamelody-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.69.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

and Spring Boot:

```
<spring.boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
```

JavaMelody "1.74.0" needs an upgrade on Spring Boot too, so in order to avoid SpringBoot upgrade right now I've tried to upgrade JavaMelody with the core version:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
      <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.74.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

This just give me this error, without any hint about what it's wrong:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at nl.famed.dcim.Application.main(Application.java:21)"
```

Any suggestion will be very helpufull!
Also, if something else is needed to show from the project, just tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I've simply neglected to make the update in a different module of the same application.